# python функция int

Tags: python

Когда в пайтоне используется шаблон функции `int([x])`, а когда `int(x)`?

Comment: Под ```int([x])``` вы имеете в виду то, что аргумент ```x``` необязателен, или же то, что в функцию передается список?
В первом случае это значит, что функцию ```int([x])``` можно вызывать без параметров, в таком случае она просто вернет 0.
Во втором случае имеем ошибку  
```TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'```

Answer (score 3):

как уже сказали в комментариях, шаблон:

```
int([x])
```

ошибочен, ибо функция int() вызывается от чисел, от строковых представлений числа либо от байт подобных объектов, но никак не от списка\ов, можно применить функцию int() для списка так:

```
map(int, [x, y, z])
```

Answer (score 1):

1. У тебя при записи переменной в квадратных скобках получился список, а список в питоне нельзя перевести в целое число.
2. Лучше пиши так: int( и сразу переменную, если у нее строчное значение) тоже самое с функциями `str()` и `float()`.